# Java not assigning data to member in subclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

So I have a super class that has two parameters in the constructor.  The super class constructor defines one memeber using a single variable but the second variable is used to check if they are null.  So in the subclass constructor I call super then define the member of the other variable.  When debugging, it skips right over the declartion using the second variable after calling super.  I'll give some nonspecific code.

```
public abstract class Foo{
    private enum type; #the enum is defined its not just enum written

    public Foo(enum type, String str){
        Objects.requireNonNull(type, "Given type must not be null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(str, "Given string input must not be null.");
        this.type = type;
     }
 ...
 methods
 ...
 }
```

Now for the subclass

```
public class Bar extends Foo{
    private String str;
    ...members...
    public Bar(enum type, String str){
        super(type, str);
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

So in debugging, the line this.str=str; is skipped completley.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you only seeing this as a debugging issue, or does the code actually behave in an unexpected way? If you could provide a [mcve] rather than pseudocode, that would really help.

Comment: So when the code runs it eventuallly hits a NullPointerException, then I went into debugging mode and saw rhe skip.  Then  inspected the variables this.str and it was null.

Comment: Okay. So now would be a good time to provide that [mcve]. Even if folks can't explain the debugger behaviour (which may well be environment-specific) we could explain the NullPointerException.